# Equivalence class/Equivalence relation question.

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let R be an equivalence relation on set A, and let a,b$\in$A. If b$\in$[a] then [b]$\subseteq$[a].

I need help proving this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: x in [b] then xRb, so if also b in [a] combine aRb with bRa by transitivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

By definition $[a]=\{b~:~b\simeq a\}$, in other words, it is the set of all things related to $a$.

So, suppose that $b\in [a]$, that means that $b\simeq a$.

Now... to prove that one set is a subset of another, take an arbitrary element in the one on the left and show that it must also be one of the right.  Remember again that $[b]=\{c~:~c\simeq b\}$ and use your properties of equivalence relations.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that the transitivity of equivalence relations can be used to prove this.